# Why do I get the message "device connection disrupted" when I connect my phone to the computer?

Tags: samsung-kies

I have a Samsung Galaxy mini gt-55570. When I try connecting my phone to the computer, I get the message "device connection disrupted" and " Kies has stopped working". What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SD card in your phone try, removing it first and try again. If it works, then good.